# Bad performance on validation set while using SMOTE

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to do classification with 2 classes. 
When I classify without [SMOTE](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/node6.html) I get (average values of 10 fold cross validation):

```
Precision       Recall            f-1
0,640950987     0,815410434       0,714925374
```

When I use smote: (oversample the minority class at 200% and k = 5) (also 10 cross validation, this means there is synthetic data in my test and train set.

```
Precision        Recall           f-1
0,831024643      0,783434343      0,804894232
```

As you can see this works well.

However, when I test this trained model on validation data (which hasn't got any synthetic data and which has not been used to construct the synthetic data point)

```
Precision        Recall           f-1
0,644335755      0,799044453      0,709791138
```

which is awful. I used a random decision forest to classify.

*Has anyone got any idea why this is happening & a solution to fix this ? Any useful tips regarding extra tests I can try to get more insight are welcome too.*

More info: I do not touch the majority class. I work in Python with scikit-learn and [this algorithm](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scikit-learn/5278) for SMOTE.

The confusion matrix on the test data (which has synthetic data): 
[image]

The confusion matrix in the validation set (which hasn't got any synthetic data nor has it been used as the basis to create synthetic data):

[image]

---

**Edit:** I read that the problem possibly lies in the fact that Tomek Links were created. Therefore [I wrote some code to remove the Tomek links](https://github.com/ojtwist/TomekLink). Though this doesn't improve the classification scores.

**Edit2:** I read that the problem possibly lies in the fact there is too much of an overlap. A solution for this is a more intelligent synthetic sample generation algorithm. Therefore I implemented

> ADASYN: Adaptive Synthetic Sampling Approach for Imbalanced Learning

. My implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/ojtwist/ADASYN). It performed worse than smote.

Comment: It is interesting that your performance goes back to the pre-SMOTE case.  Precision and Recall can be misleading when the classes are not balanced.

Answer (score 5):

Overlapping could be the reason. If there is an overlapping between the classes given the variables you have, SMOTE would be generating synthetic points affecting the separability.  As you pointed, Tomek links could be generated as well as other points harming the classification. I would suggest you try other variants of SMOTE such as Safe-SMOTE or Bordeline-SMOTE. You can find their descrption on :

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11538059_91

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-01307-2_43

Comment: Thx, I figured as much I started implementing ASASYN yesterday (another adaptive synthetic datapoint generation algorithm), will finish it later on. Else I'll have a look at one of your suggestions.